# Use TwiMl templates for sending outbound sms

Tags: spring-boot, twilio, sms, twilio-twiml

I am new to Twilio. We have a requirement in the project as follow -
Send an outbound SMS to a given number. The message body is static text and should be defined using a template on Twilio(TwiML), so that client can change the message body anytime without making any changes in the backend application.

I have gone through the Twilio documentation to understand how to use TwiML, but couldn't find any document or article which explains how to use TwiML for sending an outbound SMS. Currently I am using following code to send a SMS and the message is configured in the Spring Boot application.properties file.

```
Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber), 
                        new PhoneNumber(fromPhoneNumber), 
                        messageBody).setStatusCallback(URI.create(callBackUrl)).create();
```

Does anyone know how to use TwiML template to send an outbound SMS. Can someone help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is Twiml?
Twiml is instructions for Twilio, how to respond to an incoming phone call,SMS, etc...
[What is Twiml](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml)

It is not for outbound actions.
To initiate an SMS , you should use the Twilio api which is what you are doing when you use the sdk such as `Message.creator`